# one one continuous function from $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z\neq 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there is one one continuous function from $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z\neq 0\}?$ I tried many examples but did't found. Is there any concept about existence or non-existence of such a function? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The natural inclusion is such a function. (You didn't specify it needs to be onto.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, $$f(z)=\frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert}\ln \lvert z\rvert$$ **The idea:** $\ln x$ maps bijectively $(1,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$. So we just identify $\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$ and rescale along the radii. In fact, $\dfrac z{\lvert z\rvert}$ is the norm-1 vector in the direction of $z$.

Comment: it is clearly continuous. Is it one one?

Comment: Yes: its just a smooth radial rescaling via a bijective function.

Comment: ok thanks a lot...i am looking at your solution.

Comment: An important detail is that $\ln\lvert z\rvert$ is always positive on the domain (so you never send a vector in the opposite quadrant).

Comment: yes i got the point..... can there be Non constant analytic function from  $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z\neq 0\}$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}.$?

Comment: @neelkanth, you should post it as a different question.

Comment: ok i am going to post it....please have a look at it...thanks...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833688/non-constant-analytic-function-from-z-in-mathbbcz-neq-0-to-z-in-math

Comment: please have a look.....

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler map is
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert}(\lvert z\rvert-1)
$$
still a radial rescaling.