# Non constant analytic function from $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z\neq 0\}$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there is non constant analytic function from  $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z\neq 0\}$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}?$ According to me there is no such  non constant analytic function because if there is any such function say $f,$ then $f$ can have  either a pole or essential singularity at $z=0$. In the case of pole Picard's theorem of meromoprphic function will work and in the case of essential singularity we know that image of  any neighbourhood of essential singularity  is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, so in both of the cases we get a contradiction. So no such non constant analytic function. Am i right? Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: picard's  theorem for meromorphic theorem says that non constant meromorphic function can omit at most 2 points from its range

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If so then $1/f$ is bounded. Hence $1/f$ has a removable singularity at the origin, giving a bounded entire function.

Comment: How can we say that $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}1/f(z)$ exists?

Comment: It's a theorem in more or less any book on the subject: If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $0$ and $f$  is bounded near $0$ then $0$ is  a _removable_ singularity.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline {\mathbb{D}}$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$, via the map $z \to \dfrac{1}{z}$. So essentially you have to construct a map from $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$. Suppose the map is $f$. We already have a map, $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ given by $z \to e^z$. Compose this with $f$ to obtain a bounded entire function, which means $f$ is constant.

Comment: $\mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\}$, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks.